# What is the best practice for 'find' in the python repository pattern?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, repository-pattern

I am writing a python script with a repository pattern using SQLAlchemy. The methods I have defined as add, get, update, delete, find.

Considering there are multiple fields in my Model: field1, field2, field3. What would be the best way to make a function that is able to allow the user to search multiple fields?

Right now, what I have is:

```
def find_item(self, field1, field2, field3):
    return self.session.query(Model).filter(Model.field1 == field1, Model.field2 == field2, Model.field3 == field3).all()
```

But when user searches using field1 only, it will give error as field2 and field3 are required to complete the session query.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your fixed length of 3 parameters, you can use

```
def find_item(self, field1=None, field2=None, field3=None):
    args = []
    if field1 is not None:
        args.append(Model.field1 == field1)
    if field2 is not None:
        args.append(Model.field2 == field2)
    if field3 is not None:
        args.append(Model.field3 == field3)

    return self.session.query(Model).filter(*args).all()
```

Or for a variable number of parameters

```
def find_item(self, **kwargs):
    args = [
      (getattr(Model, fieldname) == value) for fieldname, value in kwargs.iteritems()
    ]

    return self.session.query(Model).filter(*args).all()
```

Both would be called as

```
something.find_item(field1='foo')
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed.